# Easy Way to Wrap CRON Output in HTML PRE?

Tags: cron, html, mime-types

I use Gmail and every so often I have to hack it back in that text/plain email should be rendered in a monospace font. This makes it much easier to skim system-generated reports, &c. The problems with this are that I have to re-hack Gmail every few years when they change their semantics, and I have more "developer" type colleagues who aren't going to hack their gmail to improve the legibility of these emails.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows an easy command to take a text file and wrap it in HTML and enough MIME stuff to correctly encode the message as ... ideally multipart alternative, with the HTML being the text in a PRE tag.

I mean, if I can even feed MIME output to cron?  I'd be content to pipe to an html-mime-email type command ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found your question, hope the answer can be still relevant.

I am successfully running cron jobs with HTML output for years. It needs the following vars set in the crontab before your commands:

```
CONTENT_TYPE="text/html; charset=utf-8"
CONTENT_TRANSFER_ENCODING="8bit"
```

Note it is text/html but not multipart.

I haven't found any other way of wrapping the output with `pre` tags other than just write an obvious script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '<pre>'
"$@"
echo '</pre>'
```

then using it explicitly in the crontab in front of your command.

Such approach has an minor disadvantage that the name of this script will be visible in the subject of an email sent from cron, like, if you'd call it `pre`: `Cron <user@host> pre your_command`.

Comment: What is it that actually _uses_ those two variables? It doesn't look like it's cron itself that uses them (at least not the common Vixie cron implementation). Is it the MTA (which one?)

Comment: The output of the cron job is passed to an MTA, so yea those environment variables can inform the MTA

Comment: Yep, MTA uses it. In my tested case, Postfix.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean hacking the standard email that `cron` emits when a job fails, then you cannot to this without modifying `cron`. You can emit HTML (or even multipart/alternative) from your script if you want, but it won't change the fact that `cron` will send it as a `text/plain` body.

I suggest that you wrap your `cron` jobs in an outer adaptation script that does this job. The outer adaptor always succeeds and emits no output, but internally it collects the output and exit status of its child process and sends its own email when applicable.